# Adding variable to params in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can i add user_id into params[:page] i don't want to use hidden fields.

```
@page= Page.new(params[:page])
```

Is there a way to use like

```
@page= Page.new(:name=>params[:page][:name], :user_id => current_user.id)
```

Comment: I'm curious - what's wrong with using hidden fields?

Comment: @sscirrus: Hidden fields can be seen in the HTML source on the client. If you want to add sensitive information to the model (i.e. UUID), then it would be better to add the field to the model on the server-side.

Answer (score 79):

I use this day in and day out:

```
@page= Page.new(params[:page].merge(:user_id => 1, :foo => "bar"))
```

Comment: I just want to add that this works with an unlimited number of attributes.

Comment: will this work if I do (:user_id => 1).merge(params) ?

Answer (score 19):

Instead of doing it that way, build the association (assumes you have `has_many :pages` in the `User` model):

```
@page = current_user.pages.build(params[:page])
```

This will automatically set `user_id` for the `Page` object.

Comment: @Rails101: current_user.pages.build(params[:page].merge(:other_id => other_id)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to merge the `current_user` id, you can build the proper model associations and then scope the `new()` method

**Models**

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :pages
end
```

**Controller**

```
if current_user
 @page = current_user.pages.new(params[:page])
else
 @page = Page.new(params[:page])
end
```