# Rails pass additional parameter to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

in a controller I have a create action

```
  def create

    params[:note]
    @note = current_user.notes.new(params[:note])

      if @note.save
        respond_with @note, status: :created
      else
        respond_with @note.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
  end
```

I want to pass to the model another param called current_user, how to do that and how to retrive the passed param in a model  method?

Comment: To which model do you want to pass that param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@note = Note.new(params[:note].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
```

But perhaps this is not the best way how you do it, look at this: [Adding variable to params in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350499/adding-variable-to-params-in-rails)

If you want access to current_user in model, see: [Rails 3 devise, current_user is not accessible in a Model ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742785/rails-3-devise-current-user-is-not-accessible-in-a-model)

Comment: You don't need to `merge` when you can just assign directly: `params[:note][:user_id] = current_user.id` Remember that `merge` returns a copy, so this doesn't alter the parameters but instead returns a version with additional entries.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. When I wrote the reply, I meant to use `merge` while calling `new`. ie: `Note.new(params[:note].merge(:user_id => current_user.id))`
Would it be correct?

Comment: That makes sense since you use the result. `merge` in a void context is almost always pointless.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you do that with a hidden_field.

So in your create view,  you'd add current_user as a hidden field.

```
<%= form_for @note do |f| %>
  # all your real fields
  <%= f.hidden_field :current_user current_user %>
<% end %>
```

Then in the create controller  params[:note][:current_user] would be defined,  and added to your model,  assuming your model has an attribute called 'current_user'

Comment: While adding custom hidden fields can be helpful, I wouldn't for current_user. It is too easy for a malicious user to change the content of the form before submitting. Now you've got a record in your table that says Bob did something, when really it was Alice... Move it to the controller like suggested by Mikhail.