# Rails adding params from multiple models

Tags: controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm not shure what's the right way to do this, so I hope to get some advice of how to do this 'nice'.
Let's say you have a model with multiple relations as belongs_to-statements, for example a book. A book has a author (user) and a publisher:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :publisher
```

Great. The user is signed to a publisher via a has many :through

```
has_many :contracts
has_many :publishers, through: :contracts
```

Same goes for the publisher model. Both, author and publisher have many books. So far so good.
Now you have a publisher-show-view in which you render the book's form-partial, 'cause you want to add a book directly from the publisher's 'show'-view.

Now, you want to submit the form and cause to the relations, you have to feed the book model with the publishers and the authors-data.

The question is now, how to do this. Merging data into the params in the book's create method seems to work good: [found on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350499/adding-variable-to-params-in-rails).

I've red about creating a hidden field in the form with the author_id but didn't go after it, cause it felt dirty somehow.

What would be the 'right' way to do this? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Nested models forms and Nested attributes.
You have two RailsCasts on the subject: [part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) and [part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) where you can see how it works. Also the [mandatory documentation on subject](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

If you option for this way here are an updated method versions for the latest rails versions:

```
  def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)", :class => "icon-remove")
  end

  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)
    end
    link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")")
  end
```

because the screencast version will not work on later versions of rails.