# How to trigger a JS code once when a new model is created in rails?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to have an 'Achievement Unlocked' JS animation play on my show page when someone creates a new cocktail model. So it should only play once and never again on that particular page. I'm kinda stuck on how to do that without creating a separate table for 'Achievements' in my DB. Does anyone have a simple solution? Here's my controller (the NUM, @num, and @num2 are variables I created to figure out a solution, feel free to disregurad):

```
class CocktailsController < ApplicationController
  NUM = Cocktail.count
  def index
    @cocktails = Cocktail.all
  end

  def show
    @cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:id])
    # @dose = Dose.new
    @num = NUM
  end

  def new
    @cocktail = Cocktail.new
  end

  def create
    @cocktail = Cocktail.new(cocktail_params)
    @num = NUM
    if @cocktail.photo.attached?
      @num2 = @num + 2
      @cocktail.save
      redirect_to cocktail_path(@cocktail)
    else
      redirect_to new_cocktail_path,
                  warning: "Sorry, you can't create a cocktail without
                  uploading an image"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:id])
    @cocktail.update(cocktail_params)
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def destroy
    @cocktail = Cocktail.find(params[:id])
    @cocktail.destroy

    # redirect_to root_path
  end

  private

  def cocktail_params
    params.require(:cocktail).permit(:name, :photo)
  end
end
```

My HTML (The first div is the animation's html. My current code allows the animation to play more than once in all cocktail show pages that were created after the 7th cocktail) :

```
<% if @num < 7 %>
  <div id="achievement" class="">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="copy">
      <h4>Achievement Unlocked!</h4>
      <p>Here are some internet points!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>


<div class="banner" style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4),rgba(0,0,0,0.4)), url( <% if @cocktail.photo.attached? %> <%= cl_image_path @cocktail.photo.key %> <% else %> https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewagon/fullstack-images/master/uikit/lunch.jpg <% end %>)">
  <div class="container">
    <h1><%= @cocktail.name %></h1>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<div class="center">
  <%= link_to "Add A New Dose", new_cocktail_dose_path(@cocktail), class: "btn btn-ghost" %>
</div>

<div class="cards">
<% @cocktail.doses.each do |dose| %>
  <div class="card" >
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"><%= dose.ingredient.name %></h5>
      <p class="card-text"><%= dose.description %></p>
      <%= link_to "Delete", cocktail_dose_path(@cocktail, dose), class: "btn btn-dark", method: :delete %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
</div>


<br>
<div class="center">
  <%= link_to "Back", root_path, class: "btn btn-ghost" %>
</div>
```

Comment: Pass that info in params (the info that it is first or not) in params in the redirect after crreate and check in render view `if params[:first_time].exists?` and execute JS in that case.

Comment: @ARK Could you please elaborate, sorry I'm still a beginner. I understand that I can replace my conditional statement in my HTML with "if params[:first_time].exists?", but what should I do in my controller?

Comment: In your redirect in successful #create you can pass params like so:

`redirect_to cocktail_path(@cocktail, num2: num2)`
would make the redirect path: `/cocktails/3/show?num2=<...>`
Then you could access params[:num2] from your #show view


See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430247/passing-parameters-in-rails-redirect-to) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4350499/adding-variable-to-params-in-rails)

Comment: @marzipan I copy-pasted "redirect_to cocktail_path(@cocktail, num2: num2)" in my controller and in my view I replaced the conditional in the view file with "<% if params[:num2].exists? %>" but when trying to create a cocktail I got this error 

```NameError in CocktailsController#create
undefined local variable or method `num2' for #<CocktailsController:0x00007fb55ed228f8> Did you mean? @num2 @num
```

and when I checked out the other already created cocktail pages, I got: undefined method `exists?' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Ah I solved it, I had to also modify/allow it in my stong params (cocktail_params). Thanks a lot you guys, was struggling with this for a few hours :) 

Comment: You did not need to allow it in params as it was not something being "posted" from view to controller. Nameerror means you did not define it and that happened because you were sending num2 = num2 (key-value pair in params hash) and u had not defined num2's value. You could do num2: "I am num2" or anything and that would work :)

Comment: @PierceF Shall I post this as an answer as I guess it is the answer for you.

Comment: @ARK sorry for the late reply! yes please do! and thank you once again 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass that info in params (the info that it is first or not) in params in the redirect after create and check in render view if params[:first_time].exists? and execute JS in that case.
You did not need to allow it in params as it was not something being "posted" from view to controller. NameError means you did not define it and that happened because you were sending @num2 = @num2 (key-value pair in params hash) and u had not defined num2's value. You could do num2: "I am num2" or anything and that would work :)